# Search indexing not working as expected

Tags: solr, content-search

I'm new to search and indexing. We are implementing this for a search feature on the website for the end user (not the internal search) and using Solr 4.10.3 with sc8.0 u5

1. Solr is setup with all the cores/indexes
2. I have created a patch config - *MySite.ContentSearch.Solr.MySiteIndexConfiguration.config*

which has custom configuration node

```
<indexConfigurations>
   <mysiteSolrIndexConfiguration type ..
   <indexAllFields>true</indexAllFields>
...
</indexConfigurations>
```

3. Also included required template & field IDs in respective nodes

The search works only partially. These are the issues I see:

(1) There are no results from Home page. Though I have included the home page template, its inherited template and all the other templates and fields where the term being searched, exists.

(2) To troubleshoot, I set `<indexAllFields>false</indexAllFields>` and removed all included template & field IDs from this config. But surprisingly, the search still gives results. How come !!!. Should it not return null or empty?

This is the config for web index

```
<index id="mysite_web_index" 
...
<configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/mysiteSolrIndexConfiguration" />
<crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
                <Database>web</Database>
                <Root>/sitecore/content/Home/MySite</Root>
              </crawler>
```

**code:**

```
using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("mysite_web_index").CreateSearchContext())
{
  var query = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
                    .Where(x => x.Content.Contains(searchText));
}
```

Comment: Have you rebuilt your indexes after configuration was changed?

Comment: Yes, I did that with every change I made in the config... Also.. I only rebuild the custom indexes "mysite_web_index"...should I build all of the available ones too.

Comment: Can you validate whether Lucene configs are disabled and Solr  enabled?  Also does your patch configuration show up in the showconfig page?

Comment: @Diego. All Lucene configs are disabled and I can see the patch config in the showconfig page

Comment: Do you see any warnings or errors on the logs when you are building the index?

Comment: No errors. Just this warning `You have specified both IncludeTemplates and ExcludeTemplates. This logic is not supported. Exclude templates will be ignored.`

Answer (score 1):

The search you are performing is on the `Content` property of the `SearchResultItem`:

```cs
[IndexField("_content")]
public virtual string Content { get; set; }
```

As you can see this value maps on the IndexField `_content`, which is a build-in computed field that aggregates the content.
This is why your `indexAllFields` setting doesn't make any difference.

To see why your IncludeTemplates are not working, we would need to see that config ;)
Make sure it looks something like this:

```xml
<indexConfigurations>
  <ProductIndexConfiguration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration">
    ...
    <documentOptions ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration/documentOptions">
       <include hint="list:AddIncludedTemplate">
          <Product>{843B9598-318D-4AFA-B8C8-07E3DF5C6738}</Product>
          ...
       </include>
    </documentOptions>
  </ProductIndexConfiguration>
</indexConfigurations>
```